# Ajax can't catch error sent from the ResponseEntity (Spring MVC) object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, web

In my controller:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>("Order is Fulfilled Already!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

I set the HttpStatus to BAD_Request and this controller returns

```
{"headers":{},"body":"Order is Fulfilled Already!","statusCode":"BAD_REQUEST"}
```

This is my Ajax code :

```
           $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url : "/tt/fulfill/order/${orderID}",
            dateType : 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.statusCode);
            },

            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.body);
            },
       });
```

However, `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` is catched by "success" instead of "error". (It went inside the success block).
Am I missing anything here?

Comment: i don't know about spring framework, but i believe you need to have the failed status in headers instead of body for ajax to capture it as error. maybe [this might help](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST is catched by "success" instead of
>   "error".

It mean ajax is succesfull.[**ajaxerror**](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/) occurs when ajax fails.

An ajax error function executes mostly because of [**4xx & 5xx**](http://www.seocentro.com/articles/apache/http-status-codes.html) issues

You can check the status code of this ajax.

Comment: I think BAD_REQUEST is 404? How could I actually fix my problem?